# Finding all UPnP-enabled devices on an IP address

Tags: c#, upnp

I'm currently running an M-Search to find all UPnP devices on the local network. Rather than list all devices found, however, I'd like to be able to only return those with a specific IP address (I know that this is a bit counter-productive given the use of an M-Search in the first place).

Does anyone know of a way to apply a filter to an M-Search? I'd rather filter the search criteria than try and parse out the result set, if possible.

My current M-Search string (passed to a socket connection in C#):

```
M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST:239.255.255.250:1900\r\nST:upnp:rootdevice\r\nMAN:\"ssdp:discover\"\r\nMX:3\r\n\r\n
```

Answer (score 0):

That *should* be easy: Normally M-SEARCH is a multicast request but clients may use a unicast request to a particular known address as well. The message should be otherwise identical, but the MX header is not needed because responses should be 'immediate'.

Whether a particular device supports this is another question of course.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this appears to be an optional v1.1 feature (so presumably won't be supported by any 1.0 devices)